# Flatten JSON object in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table with 1 column and rows like -

```
Row- {'category': ['mobiles'], 'specs': ['4g', '2gb ram']}
Row- {'category': ['computer'], 'specs': ['2gb ram']}
```

I want to flatten the data into 2 columns-

```
category, mobiles
specs, 4g
specs, 2gb ram
category, computer
specs, 2gb ram
```

I tried this

```
SELECT `key`,`value`
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    column_name,
    '$.*' COLUMNS (
        `key` TEXT PATH '$',
        NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            `value` VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
        )
    )
) AS jt;
```

But the key column is always null.

Comment: Your desired result loses the relationship between the categories and the specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT jsonkeystable.keyname,
       jsonvaluestable.value
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_KEYS(test.jsondata),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (
    keyid FOR ORDINALITY,
    keyname VARCHAR(64) PATH '$'
    )
  ) jsonkeystable
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  JSON_EXTRACT(test.jsondata, CONCAT('$.', jsonkeystable.keyname)),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (
    valueid FOR ORDINALITY,
    value VARCHAR(64) PATH '$'
    )
  ) jsonvaluestable
ORDER BY test.id, jsonkeystable.keyid, jsonvaluestable.valueid
```

| keyname | value |
| --- | --- |
| specs | 4g |
| specs | 2gb ram |
| category | mobiles |
| specs | 2gb ram |
| category | computer |

[Step-by-step fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-6qCUsrJ) with some remarks.

PS. Adjust the rows ordering with proper ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can extract JSON object keys dynamically into column values in the table.

Use a `UNION` of two queries, one to get the `category` rows from that property, another to get the `specs` rows.

```
SELECT 'category' AS `key`, jt.value
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( 
    column_name,
    "$.category[*]" COLUMNS (
        value TEXT PATH '$'
    )
  ) AS jt

UNION ALL

SELECT 'specs' AS `key`, jt.value
FROM table_name
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( 
    column_name,
    "$.specs[*]" COLUMNS (
        value TEXT PATH '$'
    )
  ) AS jt
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gf9rK543J4npHsYa5M9R6P/0)

Comment: Got it. 


But the query you shared above has only 2 keys.

In my use case it's hard to pinpoint all the keys. 


An ideal solution would be to simply flatten the object into 2 columns.

Comment: You can JSON_TABLE() of the result of JSON_KEYS(), but this is like three steps beyond the question we ask so often — "why did you decide to store data in JSON and then just transform it into rows and columns?"

Comment: @BillKarwin 
This is a table of product data and I  am trying to find most common features in product

Comment: I didn't realize there was a `JSON_KEYS()` function that could be used to solve your problem. The other answer uses it.